# Typescript React Component - Correct way to do redux prop types to stop TS warnings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

If you have a React component:

```
interface Chat {
  someId: string;
}
export const Chat = (props: Chat) => {}
```

and `someId` is set in your `mapStateToProps`:

```
function mapStateToProps(state: State) {
  return {
    someId: state.someId || ''
  };
}
```

When I go to use this component
`<Chat />` I should not need to specify `someId` as that is injected by redux. However, typescript complains that `is missing the following properties type 'Chat': 'someId'`

A nasty workaround is to make `someId` optional:

```
interface Chat {
  someId?: string;
}
```

But this means you then have to check the component exists in some way in the components.

Whats the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the actual usage of `<Chat />` that's triggering the warning, including how `mapStateToProps` is used?

Comment: Without including the mess of some additional logic, that is exactly how it is being used. <Chat /> is in the return statement of another functional component, and within chat someId is taken from the store and used to get some data for the component. - if you think it'll help I'll add that in - I was hoping this was a solved issue using react / redux that i just cannot find

Comment: I may be missing something, but if `someId` is taken from the store _within_ Chat (in other words, if Chat is a connected component), then Chat shouldn't accept it as a prop.

Comment: I agree with the theory - But if I don't define it as a prop - I can't access it within the component?

Comment: I agree w/ baymax's answer below. In a nutshell, there's the Chat component that needs a `someId` prop. That component definition gets passed to `connect`, which returns a component that takes whichever props aren't covered by the combo of `mapDispatch` and `mapState`. This works at the [type level](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-redux/index.d.ts#L184) as well. So because `someId` is part of `mapDispatch`'s return value, it's ultimately excluded from the connected component's prop types.

Comment: Thanks @backtick , a mixture of baymaxs answer and your explanation here really helped

Comment: Also has the side benefit of making the types much clearer and not overloading an interface which I always find to be easily done in react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define interfaces for both mapstate and mapdispatch. And use `&` operator to get component Prop type.

```js
interface StateProps {
  someId: string;
}

interface DispatchProps {
  someDispatch: () => void
}

type Props = StateProps & DispatchProps

const mapState = (state: State) => ({
  someId: state.someId || ''
})

const mapDispatch = {
  someDispatch: () => ({ type: 'SOME_ACTION_TYPE' })
}

const Chat = (props: Props) => {}

export default connect<StateProps, DispatchProps>(
  mapState,
  mapDispatch
)(Chat)
```

Comment: it would be good to include backticks comment along with this answer - as put together they solve the issue and explain why :)

Comment: Note that we specifically recommend [using the React-Redux hooks API as the default instead of `connect`](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-the-react-redux-hooks-api), partly because [the hooks are much easier to use with TypeScript](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#typing-the-useselector-hook).

Comment: From where `state` coming in `mapState `?